# about how to preview in animation window blender2.81

Tags: interface

I activate workspace in animation window, I can zoom in/out in animation window, but I can't move the view, the "little hand" tool on the right side only affect the model window, not the animation preview . How can I use that hand tool to move the view in the animation previw window?

Comment: The left area show the camera perspective. You would have to move the camera to adjust the perspective.

Comment: I moved camera but the view doesn't move with it, so odd.